A barred crossword for today

Penpa+ link
Down:
1. Doze
4. Up
6. Subtraction
9. Tortoise
11. Behave
13. Acid
15. Appropriate
16. Healthy
17. Edison
18. Liberate
21. Behemoth
22. ???
24. Antichrist
25. Calmness
28. Result
29. Enemy
31. Over
32. Dissent
34. Lethargy
35. Unburden
36. No
37. Discard
38. Nod
Across:
1. Blunt
2. Delight
3. Imaginary
4. Hilltop
5. Readers
6. Dodman (2 wds)
7. Connect
8. Stabilise
10. Aweather
12. Composure
14. Disincentive
16. Ignores
19. Unprepared
20. Disregard
22. Vacate
23. Sameness
26. Defend
27. Unconsumed
29. Deflate
30. Incompetent
33. Sane

Very simple crossword, you just enter the obvious meaning of each word in its slot (for some especially simple examples, see 4 Across, 31 Across, 36 Across, and 3 Down). The orange-highlighted center row is a description of the setter. The completed grid follows:

 


Terrible commentary ;)

It may be worth giving a few examples of clues along with their answers (you know, just for the sake of demonstrating how this crossword is perfectly normal). 4A, 31A, 36A, and 3D, for instance, seem like particularly good examples.

you mean 4D, 31D, 36D, and 3A

This is the correct solution, well done on the quick solve. I'd love to know how you worked out what exactly was going on here - how long did it take for the penny to drop, and what was it that made you suspect the truth?

@Stiv (re your comment) I noticed the title and that some of the clues seemed to have obvious answers: as I recall, 9 Across was one of the first.
